# OSMNX, plot_graph and size in pixels

Tags: python, matplotlib, osmnx

I have :

```py
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, bgcolor='k', edge_color=ec, node_size=8, edge_linewidth=1, edge_alpha=1, figsize=(20,20), dpi=300, save=True, filepath='image.png')
```

And I get an image 4650x2719 pixels. How can get an image with a width of 8500 pixels? I cannot see the link between 20, 300 and 4650.